# No Display via GPU on POST

Tags: graphics-card, display, bios, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a GPU Nvidia GTX 1050ti installed on my Gigabyte B150M D3H board. I have two monitor setup where monitor 1 (M1) is connected to the GPU via HDMI and monitor 2 (M2) is connected to the DVI on the motherboard. This second monitor has only VGA and DVI inputs so I am using DVI.

When I boot the display goes straight to the M2, for BIOS and POST display, and the M1 is blank, no input. Once the OS starts/almost done loading, the display switches from M1 to M2 and M2 goee blank, no input.

I want to use M1 as my primary monitor and want it to work on POST and BIOS screens as well. I only want to use M2 when I am working on something that requires two monitors.

I have made sure that BIOS has a setting called Initial Display Output, and it is set to PCIe 1 Slot. It also has a setting called Internal Graphics, and it is set to Auto. If I set it to disable, I lose display completely and have to reset my BIOS to get display again.

How can I get display on my M1 monitor that is connected to GPU in POST?

Comment: Does this happen if you only have M1 connected? Did you try to connect both displays to the Nvidia GPU?

Comment: no it works just perfect if I disconnect (remove the DVI cable) from M2. In this case, M1, takes over and works on POST as well. I have connected both to the GPU now, and same issue. M1 gets display after OS boots up.

Comment: But that's a different issue (likely) as Nvidia just sees one of the ports as "primary". You might be able to find that information in your manual.